# Terraform imports for newrelic slack destination for workflows is not working

Tags: newrelic, terraform-provider

I am trying to import slack destination using terraform from existing NewRelic workflows.

I have created main.tf

```
  required_version = ">= 0.13.2"
  required_providers {
    newrelic = {
      source  = "newrelic/newrelic"
      version = "~> 3.4.1"
    }
  }
}

resource "newrelic_notification_destination" "foo" {
  account_id = 1111111
  type = "SLACK"
}

When I run below command it gives me the error. Additionaly I have tried passing account_id as a variable still I am getting below error.

./alert_notification_destination_slack_v3$ terraform import newrelic_notification_destination.foo "11111111-11111-11cd-aaaaa-1111111111111aa" 

│ Error: Missing required argument
│ 
│ The argument "account_id" is required, but was not set.
╵
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend splitting provider config into a separate providers.tf file with the following:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13.2"
  required_providers {
    newrelic = {
      source  = "newrelic/newrelic"
      version = "~> 3.4.1"
    }
  }

  provider "newrelic" {
    account_id = <Your Account ID>
    api_key    = <Your Personal API Key>
    region     = <Your Region>
  }
}
```

Of course, you could do the same thing where you already have your provider info, it may just need that extra `provider "newrelic" {}` block with the account ID.